# Unable to position element inside an absolute positioned div

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 58px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 82px;
}

.icon {
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #41c363;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image: Sample]

I am trying to achieve the UI as shown in the image above using HTML and CSS.
Somehow, I am unable to center the icon class align vertical centrally.

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r9b6nqfk/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css

add `display: flex;`, `align-items: center;` to `.footer` class

```
.footer {
width: 400px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 58px;
background: #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 82px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9b6nqfk/1/)

```css
.footer {
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 58px;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 82px;
}

.icon {
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #41c363;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```